# linux loopback interface to specific interface in python

Tags: python, linux, sockets, interface, network-programming

I'm trying to send some data to a local address and then 'forward' it to an external address using a specific interface `ppp0`. I think my issue is related to packet routing/socket binding issues but I'm too much of a novice to make sense of it.

My network setup:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
10.64.64.64     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     304    0        0 wwan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
```

with the loopback:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

On the Python side, I bind the socket

```
HOST = ''
PORT_vid = 0

try:
    s_vid = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s_vid.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s_vid.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, 25, "ppp0")#this works to bind it to ppp0
    print("Socket created.")
except socket.error, msg:
    print("Failed. Error: " + str(msg))
    sys.exit()

try:
    s_vid.bind((HOST,PORT_vid))
    print("Socket binding complete.")
except socket.error, msg:
    print("Bind failed. Error: " + str(msg))
    s_vid.close()
    sys.exit()
```

Which works fine if I try to simply ping an external address. Now I send my data to a local point using `netcat`

```
#p_nc is taking some data from a local process and sending it to the local point
p_nc = subprocess.Popen(["nc", "-u", "127.0.0.1", str(s_vid.getsockname()[1])],stdin=another_process.stdout)
```

And then I listen on that local port and forward it (there are good reasons why I don't just send it off with `netcat`)

```
while 1:
    data, addr = s_vid.recvfrom(1024)
    print('local reception')

    #do stuff here with 'data' - never reached
    s_vid.sendto(data_amended,(external_ip,external_port))
```

The data has to go to the external address via `ppp0`, and using the "process to `netcat` to local to external" setup (as above) would be preferred. The `s_vid` socket does not need to listen for any external traffic, it is simply sending external and listening local.

I'm guessing my socket is bound to `ppp0` and so can't read the loopback data, but I don't know how to fix it. Either a solution on the Python end or on the ip routing end will work, but I'm new to routing and interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up simply adding a new socket to my code, which is bound to the `lo` interface (similar to how the other is bound to `ppp0`). The `lo` socket reads the local socket (`s_lo.recvfrom()` in the loop), while we keep `s_vid.sendto()`.